# Rotate a feature programmatically Open Layers

Tags: javascript, rotation, openlayers, heading

**TLDR** I want to rotate a Feature in my open layers. 

I want it to face a certain heading that I am receiving from server.

---

I know that you can make a feature spin on a point or so on:

```
window.setInterval(function() {rotateFeature(
       pointFeature, 360 / 20, origin)}, 100);
```

as from the [open layers example.](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/rotate-features.html)

But I want to be able to face it towards a heading I am given, so.

1. Can I face a feature towards a heading?
2. Can I face a feature(image) in the same way?
3. If not is it possible to automatically calculate the rotation required and position it that way?
4. Or any ideas on how I could do this with the image? (hoping not to have 360 images)

An example or such would be appreciated.

---

No luck so far using:

```
      window.setInterval(function() {rotateFeature(
        imagefeature, 150 / 360, origin)}, 1000);
        function rotateFeature(feature, angle, origin) {
            feature.geometry.rotate(angle, origin);
            }
```

Where origin is the centeroid of the image object.

Any ideas code side?

Comment: I want to rotate the Image by the "heading" I am given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use images / icons to represent vector points e.g.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features.html

Uses this png file [alt text http://openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png](http://openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png)
You should then be able to rotate the point as in the other example. You can rotate to any angle:

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.8/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.rotate

```
rotate: function(angle,origin)
```

Rotate a point around another.
Parameters

angle   {Float} Rotation angle in degrees (measured counterclockwise from the positive x-axis)

origin  {OpenLayers.Geometry.Point} Center point for the rotation

Comment: Thanks for the info. But if I were to rotate a single point(image) do I have to rotate it around based on another point or can i base it on itself and rotate it that way?

Comment: The origin parameter can be any point. To use the centroid of the vector feature (if it is a point the centroid will be the point) use:

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.8/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.getCentroid